# Tensorflow error: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, activation-function

I am struggling to implement an activation function in [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) in Python.

The code is the following:

```python
def myfunc(x):
    if (x > 0):
        return 1
    return 0
```

But I am always getting the error:

> Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond):

```
tf.cond(tf.greater(x, 0), lambda: 1, lambda: 0)
```

Another solution, which in addition supports **multi-dimensional tensors**:

```
tf.sign(tf.maximum(x, 0))
```

Note, however, that the gradient of this activation is zero everywhere, so the neural network won't learn anything with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have this error now Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'actfc1_36/activation_15/cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes

Answer (score 3):

In **TF2**, you could just decorate the function `myfunc()` with `@tf.function`:

```
@tf.function
def myfunc(x):
    if (x > 0):
        return 1
    return 0
```